# Handling the events of a Interop control in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

In a Win32 C# App, we are using a AxInterop control, it has some buttons on it like Ok, Cancel,etc...now in the C# code when I call and open the window of that AxInterop I want to see how can I know that user clicked on Ok buttton for example in that control so I can handle some stuff in C# code....

Comment: Do you have any info about the controls you are using? AxInterop is the standard name for interface dll in .net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use whatever the control exposes. You cannot capture the control events if they do not capture your click and translate it to a custom click that you can handle.

If you don't have the control documentation you can examine the controls methods/properties/events ... pressing F2.